How to attach a scroll listener on DraggableScrollableSheet?
I want to get more events, when the scrollPosition reaches it's max extent -  basic load more feature.
DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: extent,
        minChildSize: 0.075,
        maxChildSize: 0.95,
        snapSizes: const [0.075, 0.5, 0.95],
        snap: true,
        builder: (context, scrollController) {
          // I can attach the listener like this, 
          // but this might create multiple listeners, 
          // and there's no way to dispose them. 
          // When checking scrollController.hasListener it shows a 
          // warning The member 'hasListeners' can only be used within 
          // instance members // of subclasses of 
          // 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart'

          if (!scrollController.hasListeners) {
            scrollController.addListener(() {
              if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
                  scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                context.read<NearbyCubit>().getMoreEvents();
              }
            });
          }
          return Container(
           
            child: CustomScrollView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              controller: scrollController,
              slivers: [
                SliverAppBar(
                  pinned: true,
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                    ),
                  ),                  
                ),
                const _Events(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

Adding a NotificationListener only provides the extent of the sheet itself, not the scrollPosition.
How can I pass a scrollController, or detect when the max scroll extent is reached?
